# Let $f \in L^1[0,1]$. Does it hold that $\lim_{t\to\infty}t\cdot|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=0$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^1[0,1]$.

Does it hold that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}t\cdot|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=0\,?$$
I don't know if this is true or not.

Comment: See also the notion of "weak $L^1$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its true, just note that for $t>0$

$$
0\leqslant t \cdot \lambda (\{|f|>t\})\leqslant \int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f| \,d \lambda \tag1
$$

And because $f$ is integrable

$$
\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f| \,d \lambda=\int_{\operatorname{dom}(f)}|f|\,d \lambda-\int_{\operatorname{dom}(f)}|f|\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|\leqslant t\}}\,d \lambda \tag2
$$
Now, as $|f|\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|\leqslant t\}}\uparrow |f|$ pointwise as $t \to \infty $ we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to (2), showing that $\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f|\,d \lambda \to 0$ as $t \to \infty $. Then taking the limit as $t \to  \infty $ in (1) we had shown the result.∎

Comment: Are you using that $\infty\cdot 0=0$?

Comment: The first inequality implies $0\leq|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}\leq\frac{1}{t}\|f\|_1$, which implies $0\leq\lim_{t\to\infty}|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|\leq\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{t}\|f\|_1=0$, and that's why you have $\lim_{t\to\infty}|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=0$, right? And then, since $\lim_{t\to\infty}t=\infty$, we have $\lim_{t\to\infty}t\cdot|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=\infty\cdot 0=0$

Comment: But then what do we do with the factor $t$? The first inequality only implies that the limit is bounded, not that it is $0$

Comment: Doesn't the argument I mentioned also show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=0$?

Comment: I mean only the first part, that $0\leq|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|\leq\frac{1}{t}\|f\|_1$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty}|\{x:|f(x)|>t\}|=0$.

Comment: Ok now I don't get why the integral on the right goes to $0$ as $t\to\infty$

Comment: We have $$\int_{\{x \ :\ \vert f(x)\vert\geq t\}} \vert f\vert d\lambda =\int_{[0,1]} 1_{\{x\ : \ \vert f(x)\vert\geq t\}} \vert f \vert d\lambda.$$ Notice that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} 1_{\{x\ : \ \vert f(x)\vert\geq t\}} \vert f \vert = 0.$$ Also $$0\leq  1_{\{x\ : \ \vert f(x)\vert\geq t\}} \vert f \vert  \leq \vert f\vert.$$ Now invoke the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: So we don't need to use the fact that $[0,1]$ has finite measure?

Comment: But you are integrating over $\mathbb R$